# Как подставить другое значение с помощью связи в PhpMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Допустим, у меня есть таблица `books`, в ней хранятся такие данные:
id;Название_Книги;id_автора;
Я сделал в PhpMyAdmin связь id_автора с таблицей authors. Можно ли как-то при просмотре таблицы `books` выводить не id_автора, а имя автора из таблицы `authors`?

Answer (score 1):

С помощью запроса:

```
select b.id, b.Название_Книги, a.Автор
from books b
left join authors a on a.id=b.id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    books.id,
    books.name,
    authors.name
FROM
    books
LEFT JOIN authors ON books.author_id = authors.id
```

Comment: а чем ответ отличается от моего?